# Where can a save confirmation page be hooked into the Django admin? (similar to delete confirmation)

Tags: python, django

I want to emulate the delete confirmation page behavior before saving 
certain models in the admin.  In my case if I change one object, 
certain others should be deleted as they depend upon the object's now 
out-of-date state.

I understand where to implement the actual cascaded updates (inside 
the parent model's save method), but I don't see a quick way to ask 
the user for confirmation (and then rollback if they decide not to 
save). I suppose I could implement some weird confirmation logic 
directly inside the save method (sort of a two phase save) but that 
seems...ugly.

Any thoughts, even general pointers into the django codebase?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I was just about to post the same question. Did you manage to get anywhere with this problem?

Comment: Nope, I never figured this one out.  It wasn't a very common operation in my case so I just punted.

Answer (score 2):

You could overload the `get_form` method of your model admin and add an extra checkbox to the generated form that has to be ticket.  Alternatively you can override `change_view` and intercept the request.

Comment: This is how we do it, but I could see using javascript to show an confirmation screen being a lot easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means a Django expert, so this answer might misguide you.

Start looking somewhere around `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin`, especially `render_change_form` and `response_change`. I guess you would need to subclass ModelAdmin for your model and provide required behavior around those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered overriding the administrative templates for the models in question?  This [link](http://www.unessa.net/en/hoyci/2006/12/custom-admin-templates/) provides an excellent overview of the process.  In this particular situation, having a finer-grained level of control may be the best way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I've already overloaded parts of the change_form, but this particular behavior seems to be hard coded into the core (at least the post save redirect url).  Perhaps I can shadow the post save confirmation url and do something funky there though?